# Compile and consume class at runtime

Tags: c#, code-generation, metaprogramming

I'm developing a sort of a rules engine, where users define a rule as a set of conditions and actions.  Those conditions and actions are then parsed into code to be executed.  I am able to generate the code without any issue.  I'm stuck at the point of compiling it and then loading the class.

How do I take a string of dynamically generated source code and compile it at runtime?

How can I then execute that code?

I envision being able to have a static list of rules that would be updated as rules are added.  Something like:

```
static Dictionary<string, Rule> Rules { get; set; }
static void RefreshRules ()
{
    var newRules = DataLayer.GetRules().Where(r => !this.Rules.ContainsKey(r.Name));
    foreach (var rule in newRules)
    {
        this.Rules[rule.Name] = CompileRule(rule.Code);
    }
}
```

Or would I re-compile an assembly and then reload it into my already running app?

Comment: Start here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/650ax5cx.aspx; I have used the CodeDom in the past, but have no code samples handy for a proper answer.

Comment: Check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5766373/how-does-linqpad-compile-code

Comment: Is there a reason you don't want to use a rules engine, like Drools?

Comment: Have you considered using `System.Reflection.Emit` directly? Sometimes it is easier than the Expression Trees.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would you recommend to use the [Expression Trees](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397951.aspx) instead of dynamically compiling code.

When you compile some source, the resulting assembly is glued into your main application, and cannot be detached anymore. That leads to a growing memory usage, and to a potentially dangerous behaviors. The Expression Trees has been created just for target like yours.

Answer (score 3):

Some rough example (compiling source code, creating instance, calling method with params using Reflection):

```
CodeDomProvider P = System.CodeDom.Compiler.CodeDomProvider.CreateProvider("C#");
CompilerParameters O = new CompilerParameters();
O.GenerateInMemory = true;
O.ReferencedAssemblies.Add(@"System.dll");
//O.ReferencedAssemblies.Add(@"System.Net.dll");

O.IncludeDebugInformation = false;

CompilerResults R = P.CompileAssemblyFromSource(O, new string[] { "using System; using System.Reflection; namespace ABC.TestXXX {     // your source code goes here }" });

Assembly _B_ = R.CompiledAssembly;
// create an instance
object YY = _B_.CreateInstance("ABC.TestXXX.MyClass");
// call method returning bool and taking one string and one object
YR = (bool)_B_.GetType("ABC.TestXXX.MyClass").GetMethod("TestB").Invoke(YY, new object[] { "Hallo", SomeObject });
```

Some links with details:

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.codedom.compiler.codedomprovider%28v=VS.100%29.aspx
- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.codedom.compiler.compilerparameters.aspx

For your case you could make the rules Action<>/delegates which in turn call the compiled methods and put those into the Dictionary<>... so it becomes rather readable when calling them etc.