# calculate result from a string expression dynamically

Tags: c#

Is there a way to calculate the result of a string expression, for example 
`mystring = "2*a+32-Math.Sin(6)"` dynamically knowing that **a** is a variable that I have, may be there is some dynamic solution or using `System.Reflection`

```
string mystring = "2*a+32-Math.Sin(6)"`;
decimal result = SomeMethod(mystring,3); // where a = 3 for example
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

How about making javascript calculate your expression?

```
Type scriptType = Type.GetTypeFromCLSID(Guid.Parse("0E59F1D5-1FBE-11D0-8FF2-00A0D10038BC"));

dynamic obj = Activator.CreateInstance(scriptType, false);
obj.Language = "javascript";

var res = obj.Eval("a=3; 2*a+32-Math.sin(6)");
```

Comment: what's that guid, is there a way to avoid that

Comment: can we use interop between .net & msscript COM ? without that GUID

Comment: @SéddikLaraba No I don't think. why don't you want to use that guid? what is wrong with it?

Comment: @SéddikLaraba You can also add a COM reference in your project to create that javascript object. Isn't that easier?

Comment: does that works on any system, & doesn't require any thing to be registred, cause i don't want my application to fail if that ClassID doesn't exist @L.B

Comment: i'll add it as reference that's better

Comment: @SéddikLaraba Referencing COM object or creating with CLSID, all are equal. Use whatever you want.

Comment: i've added **msscript.ocx** to my references, its working great, thank you !!

Answer (score 6):

You can use [Compute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.compute.aspx) methood of Datatable in `SomeMethod` in following way:

```
       static decimal Somemethod(int val)
        {
            var result = (decimal)new DataTable().Compute(string.Format("2*{0}+32-{1}", val, Math.Sin(6)), "");
            return result;
        }
```

Simply, you can call like this:

```
        result = Somemethod(3);
```

Comment: This is the only solution that worked out of the box for me, without having to do any parsing. Really hidden gem in my opinion.

Answer (score 5):

if found this its working perfectly, sorry for the bother, all I wanted is on the fly compiler. & this what i get

```
MessageBox.Show(Eval("5*3-Math.Sin(12) + 25*Math.Pow(3,2)").ToString());

public static object Eval(string sCSCode)
    {

        CodeDomProvider icc = CodeDomProvider.CreateProvider("C#");
        CompilerParameters cp = new CompilerParameters();

        cp.ReferencedAssemblies.Add("system.dll");
        cp.ReferencedAssemblies.Add("system.xml.dll");
        cp.ReferencedAssemblies.Add("system.data.dll");
        cp.ReferencedAssemblies.Add("system.windows.forms.dll");
        cp.ReferencedAssemblies.Add("system.drawing.dll");

        cp.CompilerOptions = "/t:library";
        cp.GenerateInMemory = true;

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("");
        sb.Append("using System;\n");
        sb.Append("using System.Xml;\n");
        sb.Append("using System.Data;\n");
        sb.Append("using System.Data.SqlClient;\n");
        sb.Append("using System.Windows.Forms;\n");
        sb.Append("using System.Drawing;\n");

        sb.Append("namespace CSCodeEvaler{ \n");
        sb.Append("public class CSCodeEvaler{ \n");
        sb.Append("public object EvalCode(){\n");
        sb.Append("return " + sCSCode + "; \n");
        sb.Append("} \n");
        sb.Append("} \n");
        sb.Append("}\n");

        CompilerResults cr = icc.CompileAssemblyFromSource(cp, sb.ToString());
        if (cr.Errors.Count > 0)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("ERROR: " + cr.Errors[0].ErrorText,
               "Error evaluating cs code", MessageBoxButton.OK,
               MessageBoxImage.Error);
            return null;
        }

        System.Reflection.Assembly a = cr.CompiledAssembly;
        object o = a.CreateInstance("CSCodeEvaler.CSCodeEvaler");

        Type t = o.GetType();
        System.Reflection.MethodInfo mi = t.GetMethod("EvalCode");

        object s = mi.Invoke(o, null);
        return s;

    }
```

Comment: Do you want to create a new assembly(which will use `csc` internally) everytime `sCSCode` changes? Just create a loop and see the performance.

Comment: is it that bad, because i want to use if possible .Net internal methods, if its too expensive, i'll take the javascript solution

Comment: object o with an instance can be stored for a better performance and invoked later

Answer (score 3):

Here are some of the most popular approaches that I am aware of for evaluating string expressions dynamically in C#.

### Microsoft Solutions

- [C# CodeDomCodeProvider](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.codedom.compiler.codedomprovider?view=netframework-4.7.2):

  - See [How LINQ used to work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5766373/how-does-linqpad-compile-code) and this [CodeProject article](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/11939/Evaluate-C-Code-Eval-Function)
- [Roslyn](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn):

  - See this [article on Rosly Emit API](https://joshvarty.com/2016/01/16/learn-roslyn-now-part-16-the-emit-api) and this [StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43630318/184528)
- [DataTable.Compute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.compute.aspx):

  - See this [answer on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12431343/184528)
- [Webbrowser.Document.InvokeScript](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.htmldocument.invokescript?view=netframework-4.7.2)

  - See this [StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7322420/calling-javascript-object-method-using-webbrowser-document-invokescript)
- [DataBinder.Eval](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.databinder.eval?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2#overloads)
- [ScriptControl](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/visualstudio/visual-studio-6.0/aa227400(v=vs.60))

  - See [this answer on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12431286/calculate-result-from-a-string-expression-dynamically/12431435#12431435) and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16075775/calling-the-javascript-functions-inside-c-sharp-for-a-64-bit-project?noredirect=1&lq=1)

### Non-Microsoft solutions (not that there is anything wrong with that)

- Expression evaluation libraries:

  - [Flee](https://github.com/mparlak/Flee)
  - [DynamicExpresso](https://github.com/davideicardi/DynamicExpresso/)
  - [NCalc](https://archive.codeplex.com/?p=ncalc)
- Roll your own a language building toolkit like:

  - [Irony](https://archive.codeplex.com/?p=irony)
  - [Jigsaw](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/272494/Implementing-Programming-Languages-using-Csharp)

Answer (score 2):

I don't think there's any native support for what you are asking, however there are a number of ways to accomplish it, none of which are totally trivial but in the order that I think they are easy:

- leverage an embedded language with the expression support you desire.
  For example iron ruby: http://ironruby.codeplex.com/
- use the C# compiler from your program as in
  [How does LINQPad compile code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5766373/how-does-linqpad-compile-code).
- write your own parse with something like irony:
  http://irony.codeplex.com/
- Once parsed you could use expression trees to get your result:
  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397951.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Make abstract class With the methods you want to use to evaluate the expressions. In run time make a new class that inherits that one. I will share the code soon.

as promised here is the code to do it:

```
    public class BaseClass
    {
    public BaseClass(){}
    public virtual double Eval(double x,double y){return 0;}
}
public class MathExpressionParser
{
    private BaseClass Evalulator=null;
    public MathExpressionParser(){}
    public bool Intialize(string equation)
    {
        Microsoft.CSharp.CSharpCodeProvider cp=new Microsoft.CSharp.CSharpCodeProvider();
        System.CodeDom.Compiler.ICodeCompiler comp=cp.CreateCompiler();
        System.CodeDom.Compiler.CompilerParameters cpar=new CompilerParameters();

        cpar.GenerateInMemory=true;
        cpar.GenerateExecutable=false;
        cpar.ReferencedAssemblies.Add("system.dll");
        cpar.ReferencedAssemblies.Add("EquationsParser.exe");   //Did you see this before;

        string sourceCode="using System;"+
                          "class DrivedEval:EquationsParser.BaseClass" +
                          "{"+   
                                  "public DrivedEval(){}"+
                                  "public override double Eval(double x,double y)"+
                                  "{"+
                                        "return "+ /*Looook here code insertion*/ equation +";"+
                                  "}"+
                          "}";
        //the previouse source code will be compiled now(run time);
        CompilerResults result=comp.CompileAssemblyFromSource(cpar,sourceCode);

        //If there are error in the code display it for the programmer who enter the equation
        string errors="";
        foreach(CompilerError rrr in result.Errors)
        {
            if(rrr.IsWarning)
                continue;
            errors+="\n"+rrr.ErrorText;
            errors+="\n"+rrr.ToString();
        }
        //You Can show error if there in the sourceCode you just compiled uncomment the following
        //MessageBox.Show(errors);
        if(result.Errors.Count==0&&result.CompiledAssembly!=null)
        {
            Type objtype=result.CompiledAssembly.GetType("DrivedEval");
            try
            {
                if(objtype!=null)
                {
                    Evalulator=(BaseClass)Activator.CreateInstance(objtype);
                }
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message,"Error in Creation the object");
            }
            return true;
        }
        else return false;
    }
    public double evaluate(double x,double y)
    {
        if(Evalulator==null)
            return 0.0;
        return this.Evalulator.Eval(x,y);
    }
}
```

and you will need to do the following simple test to make sure it works:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{

    if(parser.Intialize(textBox1.Text)==false)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Check equation");
    return;
}
textBox4.Text=(parser.evaluate(double.Parse(textBox2.Text),double.Parse(textBox3.Text))).ToString();
}
```