# Calling the Javascript functions inside C# for a 64 bit project

Tags: c#, javascript, 64-bit, eval, clsid

I am trying to call the Javascript function "eval" from inside C# code (to utilise the string to operators parser). I used the following code:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/12431435/712700

It crashes though with the following message--- :

> **Exception Details:** System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID
>   {0E59F1D5-1FBE-11D0-8FF2-00A0D10038BC} failed due to the following
>   error: 80040154 Class not registered (Exception from HRESULT:
>   0x80040154 (REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG)).

I believe the problem is because the project/machine is 64 bit. I do not want to change the project to 32 bit, is there another CLSID I can use to make it work with 64 bit? Or is there another approach to simply utilise the "eval" function from Javascript within C# code?

Comment: You could try a different embedded engine? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/172753/embedding-javascript-engine-into-net-c

Answer (score 1):

You are referring to the following code

```
Type scriptType = Type.GetTypeFromCLSID(Guid.Parse("0E59F1D5-1FBE-11D0-8FF2-00A0D10038BC"));

dynamic obj = Activator.CreateInstance(scriptType, false);
obj.Language = "javascript";

var res = obj.Eval("a=3; 2*a+32-Math.sin(6)");
```

The above ClSID is actually for the ScriptControl

- [Adding a ScriptControl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa227400%28v=vs.60%29.aspx) - Language Parameter
- [Using ScriptControl Methods](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa227637%28v=vs.60%29.aspx) - Eval Method

From the 2 above links you will see that this is VB6 related and if you want to use the code above as mentioned in your question you will need **msscript.ocx**. Please check if you have this file. You may have to register it correctly using regsvr32

I am using a 64-bit machine and I see the file in the following folder `C:\Windows\SysWOW64`

Comment: Thanks for that, I have the file in the same location as you. I referenced it in my project and also registered it with regsvr32, I still get the same error unfortunately.

Comment: You need the x64 version, which I don't think exists.