# Cannot evaluate. Expression 'System.Data.NameNode' is not an aggregate

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, datatable, .net-standard

I am trying the evaluate an expression using DataTable, But it's throwing the below exception on line `var temp = dt.Compute(formula, filter);` I have followed [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.datatable.compute?view=net-6.0) documentation but it didn't help me.

> Cannot evaluate. Expression 'System.Data.NameNode' is not an aggregate

```
string formula = "(Column * 2)";
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
dt.Columns.Add("Column");

string filter = "Column = 1"
var temp = dt.Compute(formula, filter);
```

The expected output is 2 here. I have followed [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12431343/6527049) answer. I am just avoiding using any external library. because I tried to Flee library but it's quite unstable.

So if you pass value 3 in place of 1 to this, then it should return 6.

Comment: You need two columns.  One for the initial value and one for the formula.

Comment: @jdweng tried with adding more columns, But still the same issue, Do you have any working example?