# problem with beforeunload event in WebBrowser control c# winform

Tags: javascript, c#, winforms, webbrowser-control, web-to-winforms

I have written logic to logout from web application in `beforeunload` even, as follows:

```
window.addEventListener("beforeunload", function (event) {  
   //Logout logic
   //Calling logout api with values from session
   //clearing the session on success 
});
```

it is working fine in all web browsers (IE, Mozilla, Chrome), however It is not working from `WebBrowser` control in `winform` application.

What could be the reason behind it?

PS: there is nothing wrong with javascript, when I call this same script by invoking it as below, it works fine:

```
   HtmlElement head = webBrowser4.Document.GetElementsByTagName("head")[0];
   HtmlElement scriptEl = webBrowser4.Document.CreateElement("script");
   IHTMLScriptElement element = (IHTMLScriptElement)scriptEl.DomElement;
   element.text = @"function Logout() {
   $.ajax({
         url: '/api/Logout',
         type: ""GET"",
         contentType: ""application/json;charset=utf-8"",
         success: function(returnVal) {
                    },
         complete: function() {
                     sessionStorage.clear();
                    },
         error: function(returnVal) {
                        }
                    });
                 }";
     head.AppendChild(scriptEl);
     webBrowser4.Document.InvokeScript("Logout");
```

What is the problem with `beforeunload` event in `WebBrowser` control in `winform`?

Comment: Try to use `InvokeScript` method, here is a thread https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7322420/calling-javascript-object-method-using-webbrowser-document-invokescript

Comment: What if I don't have control over the logout implementation in the future?

Comment: If you expect to handle it in close event of the form, it will not work. But if you expect it work when navigating to another address, it works properly.

Comment: Just in case you want user start a new session (not being logged in) when you open your application, you can disable cache and cookies. Take a look at [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52133282/3110834).

Comment: @RezaAghaei thanks for your help, but because of application requirements this will not work for me.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try it without listener?

```
window.onbeforeunload = function(event)
```