# Shortest code to convert a Unicode-like string to a real Unicode string

Tags: java, string, unicode

I am new to Java and have been battling this problem with google-fu ad experimentation for the last hour. I need to convert s1 to s2, where s1 and s2 are:

```
    String s1 ="\\u00C1";
    //...
    String s2 ="Á";
```

Comment: why do you use `\\\` in your string ?

Comment: I get these types of string from Twitter API, so, i dont have control over it.

Comment: Are you using the JSON version of the API? If so, you should be using a JSON parser, which will *take care of this for you*, not re-inventing the wheel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to scan the string to find the "\u" part, then extract the following four characters into a separate string, then use `Integer.parseInt(String s, int radix)` with a radix of 16 to convert `00C1` to an `int`, and then cast that `int` to `char`.

Comment: Thank you. I hoped for a shorter solution, like maybe using regex replacement functions. You really have to parse the string on character-by-character level, huh?

Comment: I am afraid so. At least I do not know of any shorter solution. I mean, if there was a shortcut, I think that [those guys answering that question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/53844/how-can-i-evaluate-a-c-sharp-expression-dynamically) a while ago would have mentioned it.

Answer (score 0):

```
$ cat Test.java
public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String s = "\u00C1";
        System.out.println(s);
    }   
}

$ javac Test.java
$ java Test
Á
```

automatically

Comment: I think that if she really meant `"\u00C1"` instead of `"\\u00C1"` she would have figured it out by herself and she would not be asking the question.

Comment: yeah, probably my answer was too naive. sorry.

Comment: No, wait, let's see what she says first.

Comment: Yes, this solution would be too obvious for me. The string in question really has two backslashes.