# How to compute expression

Tags: c#, expression

Consider this code fragment;

```
int sum = 0;
sum = Expression.Evaluate("1+1");
```

where the value of sum = 2

I do have an expression that will compute values but i want that expression to be build programatically then evaluate the result. I don't have any idea what class or namespace that I will dealing with. Anyone can help me.

Comment: `I do have an expression that will compute values`. does that means the code fragment you provided is working as expected? `i want that expression to be build programatically`. can you provide an example like input and output.

Comment: This answer is probably what you're looking for: http://stackoverflow.com/a/53852/1106671

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I evaluate a C# expression dynamically?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/53844/how-can-i-evaluate-a-c-sharp-expression-dynamically). Voting to close as duplicate. If it is homework - mark as such with details on what you need help with, otherwise it is already covered before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use Expression Trees:

> Expression trees represent code in a tree-like data structure, where
>   each node is an expression, for example, a method call or a binary
>   operation such as x < y.
>
> You can compile and run code represented by expression trees.

- [Expression Trees (C# and Visual Basic)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397951.aspx)
- [Expression Tree Basics](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/charlie/archive/2008/01/31/expression-tree-basics.aspx)

**Note**: This problem can be solved using `System.Reflection.Emit` and work directly with MSIL, but the resulting code is hard to write and read.

After a little browsing, I suggest you checkout Flee on Codeplex: [Fast Lightweight Expression Evaluator](http://flee.codeplex.com/)  :

> Flee is an expression parser and evaluator for the .NET framework. **It
>   allows you to compute the value of string expressions such as sqrt(a^2
>   + b^2) at runtime**. It uses a custom compiler, strongly-typed expression language, and lightweight codegen to compile expressions
>   directly to IL. This means that expression evaluation is extremely
>   fast and efficient.

Comment: I used http://jint.codeplex.com/ once for this long time ago. But that was just for prototyping only.

Answer (score 0):

You can build Expressions trees either using lambdas or by building them programatically using classes in the System.Linq.Expressions namespace.

See [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397951.aspx) for more info.

Answer (score 0):

Have you seen http://ncalc.codeplex.com ?

It's extensible, fast (e.g. has its own cache) enables you to provide custom functions and varaibles at run time by handling EvaluateFunction/EvaluateParameter events. Example expressions it can parse:

```
Expression e = new Expression("Round(Pow(Pi, 2) + Pow([Pi2], 2) + X, 2)");

  e.Parameters["Pi2"] = new Expression("Pi * Pi");
  e.Parameters["X"] = 10;

  e.EvaluateParameter += delegate(string name, ParameterArgs args)
    {
      if (name == "Pi")
      args.Result = 3.14;
    };

  Debug.Assert(117.07 == e.Evaluate());
```

It also handles unicode & many data type natively. It comes with an antler file if you want to change the grammer. There is also a fork which supports MEF to load new functions.

It also supports logical operators, date/time's strings and if statements.