# To place the script fetched from SQLite table in to my code at runtime ?

Tags: c#, database, sqlite, codedom

In sqlite i had placed the Function inside the table which i am fetching using c# code . I want to use that Function at runtime inside my code . (Eg : If i place function to add two number inside table , i want that code to be include in my code for adding two numbers .)

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar question a (long) while ago. This might help you: [How can I evaluate a C# expression dynamically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53844/how-can-i-evaluate-a-c-sharp-expression-dynamically)

Basically, it will boil down to creating a new assembly at runtime with reflection, using `CSharpCodeProvider.CompileAssemblyFromSource`.

I suggest you use a dynamic language instead, that is, use IronPython to define your source in sqlite and then host IronPython from C#. This should be easier to do, but will still let you access the rest of your application from these functions.

Comment: Thnxs for reply , Actually i want to add this code in between my line of codes (inside .cs file ) .

Comment: For future purpose i do not want to access code ,only thing to modify code is to go through database .