# call a c# function that is defined in a string

Tags: c#, string

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I evaluate a C# expression dynamically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53844/how-can-i-evaluate-a-c-sharp-expression-dynamically)

Let me describe my issue in an example. There is a string variable in my program:

```
string func = @"
void printHello()
{
    Console.WriteLine(""Hello world!"");
}
";
```

Is there any method to let me call this printHello function?

Thanks for any replies.

Comment: that won't even compile. what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Assuming he is looking for runtime evaluation of C# this is a dup question, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/53844/how-can-i-evaluate-a-c-sharp-expression-dynamically

Comment: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/304655

Comment: You need a `\ ` in order to continue a string in a new line. But a `"\n"` will not be included.

Comment: And why would you like to write your own code inside a string???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can dynamically create and execute code using [CodeDomProvider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.codedom.compiler.codedomprovider.aspx).

Look here for an example:  http://blogs.msdn.com/b/digitalnetbizz/archive/2004/01/31/create-assembly-in-memory-and-run-it.aspx

Answer (score 2):

Look at the CS-Script, it's a open source C# Script execution engine

http://www.csscript.net/