# Can you call a place in an array with a char that is a valid int but defined as a string?

Tags: c#, arrays, variables

For example, you have the array (called array1): 
`{"1","2","3"}`

And the string (called string1): `"0"`

Can you do the following: `array1[string1]`

And have it equal: `"1"`

I have checked [How can I evaluate a C# expression dynamically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53844/how-can-i-evaluate-a-c-sharp-expression-dynamically) and [call a c# function that is defined in a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11593633/call-a-c-sharp-function-that-is-defined-in-a-string) however I did not understand the answers. I apologize.

When I try `string1 = int.Parse(string1);` I get an error:

Or string1 = Convert.ToInt32(string1); :

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'int' to 'string'

To elaborate, (sorry if my description wasn't very clear), my code does this:

```
btnName =  btn.Name.ToString(); //btnName for example == btn01
btnCo1 = btnName[3].ToString(); // btnCo1 will equal "0"
btnCo2 = btnName[4].ToString(); //btnCo2 will equal "1"
btnCo1 = Convert.ToInt32(btnCo1); //I want btnCo1 as a int to use like so :
btnCo2 = Convert.ToInt32(btnCo2);
   grid[btnCo1][btnCo2] //grid is a jagged array
```

Comment: Yes you can try and convert the string to an int so array1[int.parse(string1)] but, if it doesnt find an int that will error.

Comment: You can convert string - array1[Convert.ToInt32(string1)]

Comment: You can't write that because the index of an array should be an integer and "0" is a string not an integer. C# is not VB.NET with Option Strict Off. Of course you can implement your own class over an array and implemet yourself a string indexer like you can do for example with the DataRow fields collection

Comment: `string1 = int.Parse(string1);` Do you see what you're trying to do here?

Comment: I am trying to save the string1 as a int for future use. So that I can use array1[string1] without trouble.

Comment: You're not trying to save it as an int though. you're trying to save it as a string.

Comment: You can´t change a variables datatype. See my edit.

Comment: apologies for such a badly worded question. thank you for your edit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to parse the string to int, preferably using [`TryParse`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/f02979c7(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
int idx;
if (Int32.TryParse(string1, out idx)) Console.WriteLine(array1[idx]);
```

Other way would be using `Convert.ToIn32`. However this might throw an exception if `string1` cannot be converted to int, for example if it contains `"Hello World"`.

EDIT concerning yours: you can´t change a variables data-type once you´ve declared it. So if `btnCo1` already *is* a `string` you can´t change it to be an `int`, you have to define a new variable for it:

```
int idx1 = Convert.ToInt32(btnCo1);
int idx2 = Convert.ToInt32(btnCo2);

DoSomething(grid[idx1][idx2]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can, just parse the string index to int.

```
string[] array = new string[]{ "a", "b" };
string idx = "0";

Console.WriteLine(array[Convert.ToInt32(idx)]); //Will log "a"
```

See [fiddle here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/PQmCwz)