# Implementing logic/business rules in application without compile/deploy process?

Tags: java, soa, rules, business-logic, rule-engine

My current application has a number of rules in the form of `if-else` conditional statements that work on some parameters to either modify some set of variables or set/unset other variables. Due the increasing clients that we are having, the application code is now getting *cluttered* with these if-else rules. Also, these rules are not static they change quite frequently *tweaked*, some are made to expire other's activated etc. I have seen that drools etc based on JSR094 provide this functionality to separate logic/rules from application source code.

My requirement is not so complex, I don't need complex rule visualization software, editing UI, etc. but definitely dynamic(modifications/editable rules), also my requirement requires low latency as it processes some 100s of million requests a day.

Any ideas of a **light weight** implementation to solve this as I feel drools is overkill?

My platform for development is Java. 
Example rule:

```
if ( age > 15 && item belongs_to(footwear) || using(mobile_device) ) 
        discount = 2%
```

Comment: Drools would fit perfect in implementing this.

Comment: So you're saying you want the advantages of a rules engine, but you wouldn't want to use a rules engine... The only end result is going to be you implementing your own one, and that's probably not optimal.

Answer (score 0):

I strongly suggest you use a proper rule engine, drools, flexrule... If you do not like using those solution, you always can find some expression evaluation libraries that let you to parse  and execution a string based expression.

Comment: is there a list of major companies that use drools in production like twitter, facebook etc ? Any white papers that describe how it scales/performance with more rules and dynamism ( edits to rules ) ?

Comment: I am not aware of such a list, when there is a complex business domain e.g. healthcare, inventory, finance or a system that requires to be compliant with regulations then business rule approach make sense. Or the other usage can be making a system flexible to change, i.e. more configurable and adaptable, have a look at those industries. Also [here](http://www.flexrule.com/archives/business-rule-engine-bre/) describes the differences between types of rules. Performance and scalability of rules execution depends on complexity of the rules  and the algorithm they utilize to execute the rules.

Comment: Not sure why some don't like this answer, but here is something to evaluate expression dynamically http://stackoverflow.com/questions/53844/how-can-i-evaluate-a-c-sharp-expression-dynamically
If you don't do a heavy pattern matching, Drools as you mentioned is an overkill. If you are after a commercial one, you can check this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vXIDYl7D1Rc) as well.
(Disclaimer: I work for FlexRule.)