# How to evaluate a dynamic expression using IronJS?

Tags: c#, ironjs

I have an expression like `"(((2+5)*1000)/((30-20)*7))"` How can I evaluate the expression using IronJS from C#.
The expected result is 100.

I tried the top two rated answers described in [How can I evaluate a C# expression dynamically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53844/how-can-i-evaluate-a-c-sharp-expression-dynamically) and it worked in those ways.Fine.

I have also looked into the solution proposed by **@Rudolf_Abel** and **@Jeno Laszlo** mentioned in the comment that IronJS is a better choice.

Now I am trying the same with IronJS. Is it possible.How ? I have read some article on IronJs (e.g. [here](http://www.dotnetfunda.com/articles/show/3165/calculator-application-using-ironjs-and-wpf-by-invoking-an-external-ja) is one) but just could not fit that into the requirement.

N.B.~ This is for my own sake of interest I am performing this experiment.

Comment: Are you determined to use IronJS or are you open to using other expression evaluators?

Comment: @Corey, this time the experiment will be by using IronJS (:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's [a sample](https://github.com/fholm/IronJS/blob/master/Src/Tests/UnitTests/IE9/IE9TestFixture.cs) from IronJS source, and here's [another one](https://github.com/fholm/IronJS/issues/74#issuecomment-1565881).

So, your code will be something like this:

```
private static void Run()
{
        var ctx = new IronJS.Hosting.CSharp.Context();

        dynamic a = ctx.Execute("var a = (((2+5)*1000)/((30-20)*7)); a;");
        Console.WriteLine(a);
}
```

P.S. As for me, I'd prefer to use C# scripting API instead. Stable version will be released with VS2015 update1 (coming soon) and nightly builds are in a good condition, I've had no troubles with them.

All you need to start coding: [small intro](http://daveaglick.com/posts/compiler-platform-scripting) and [nuget package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Scripting). Good luck!:)

Comment: only a small change , should be object a and not dynamic a

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this gonna help, but please try it out.

```
IronJS.Hosting.Context jsContext;
jsContext = IronJS.Hosting.Context.Create();
jsContext.Execute("(function(){return eval('(((2+5)*1000)/((30-20)*7))');})()");
```

Comment: yoiu'r also worked with a small change  var jsContext = new IronJS.Hosting.CSharp.Context();