# How to Parse a String to Logical Condition in C#

Tags: c#, string-parsing, jsonparser

I am looking for a nuget package which could help me to parse a string to a logical condition in C#. I have a configuration file in json, where users can configure the logic as follows.

```
"condition": "(item1 AND item2) OR item3",
```

This should be parsed and used in a if condition as follows.

```
if((item1 && item2) || item3){
}
```

Comment: what you need is to write a logic to parse the string and return the final outcome of it based on the values of `item(s)` stored in some dictionary.

Comment: We need more information. What format are the items? E.g. are they expressed in code? What language? Can you give some examples?

Comment: please review below address,Maybe help your https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53844/how-can-i-evaluate-a-c-sharp-expression-dynamically

Comment: Try Dynamic LINQ more details here: https://dynamic-linq.net/

Comment: If you're really keen, you can use Roslyn.  Great learning experience as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should try the `DynamicExpresso` NuGet package. It allows you to interpret and execute strings as expressions in C#. This might work after you install that library:

```
var yourString = "(item1 && item2) || item3";
using DynamicExpresso;
var i = new Interpreter();
i.SetVariable("item1", true);
i.SetVariable("item2", true);
i.SetVariable("item3", true);
bool result = i.Eval<bool>(yourString);
```

Here's the GitHub page to learn its usage: https://github.com/dynamicexpresso/DynamicExpresso

Comment: Give an example of `yourString` for the rep?

Comment: The question's string should work right: ```(item1 AND item2) OR item3```

Comment: How does it know what `item1`, `item2`, and `item3` are?

Comment: ```i.SetVariable("item1", True);``` should work

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. Thank you. But the string has to change in to "(item1 && item2) || item3" in order to run.