# Convert string to local variable name

Tags: c#

I simply need to get the value of some local floats in my code, there are so many that I want to get them with a string name input.

I know there are already many thread about this, but it's always over complicated and the solutions don't work when implementing them.

So far I know I can use reflection and the GetProperty() method, but it doesn't return a float !

```
// the input name of the variable I want to read
public string variableName = "a";

// a loop
void Update
{
    // one of the local floats I want to read the value
    float a = some stuff;
    float b = some stuff;
    (...)

    // the variable I want to assign one of the float according to the input name
    float variableRead;

    // what I found so far
    float variable = this.GetProperty(variableName ).GetValue(this);
    // DOESN'T WORK, it return an object instead of a float !
}
```

So how to simply get the floats ?
Note : the variables are locals, don't know if it changes anything.
And I don't care if it's not performant, just need it to be simple it's for debugging.

Comment: Sounds perfect for a `Dictionary<string, float>`: https://learn.microsoft.com/it-it/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.dictionary-2?view=net-7.0

Comment: If you want to dynamically resolve an expression use [Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.Scripting](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.Scripting/) as suggested by [#Ridkuma](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5466644/ridkuma) in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53844/how-can-i-evaluate-a-c-sharp-expression-dynamically/43630318#43630318)

Answer (score 4):

Don't use all these individual variables in the first place.  Use a `Dictionary<string, float>` to store the values with keys.  Then using the key to look up the value is trivial.  For example:

```
var myFloats = new Dictionary<string, float>();
myFloats.Add("a", 123);
myFloats.Add("b", 234);
// ...

float variableRead = myFloats[variableName];
```

> Smart data structures and dumb code works a lot better than the other way around.
> -Eric S. Raymond

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't work because as you said these are local variables and what you can access with `this.GetProperty()` are properties of a class.
A property looks like this:
`public float A { get; set; }`

Your code should work like that:

```
class Foo {
    public string variableName = "A";
    public float A { get; set; }

// a loop
void Update
{
    A = some stuff;
    float b = some stuff;
    (...)
    float variableRead;

    float variable = (float) this.GetType().GetProperty(propertyName).GetValue(this, null);
}
```

Comment: There's no method in the class called `GetProperty`.

Comment: You are right. Would be something like this I guess: `this.GetType().GetProperty(propertyName).GetValue(this, null);`

Comment: I suggest editing your answer with that correction then. :)

Comment: You are right. Corrected it.

Answer (score 0):

Local variables are stored on the stack, and there's no direct way to access them using reflection.

```
public class FloatReader
{
private Dictionary<string, Func<float>> localVariables = new 
   Dictionary<string, Func<float>>();

public void RegisterVariable(string name, Func<float> variableGetter)
{
    localVariables[name] = variableGetter;
}

public float GetVariable(string name)
{
    if (localVariables.ContainsKey(name))
    {
        return localVariables[name]();
    }
    else
    {
        throw new ArgumentException("Variable not found: " + name);
    }
}

public static void Main()
{
    FloatReader reader = new FloatReader();

    float a = 10.0f;
    float b = 20.0f;

    reader.RegisterVariable("a", () => a);
    reader.RegisterVariable("b", () => b);

    string variableName = "a";
    float variableValue = reader.GetVariable(variableName);

    Console.WriteLine(variableName + " = " + variableValue);

    variableName = "b";
    variableValue = reader.GetVariable(variableName);

    Console.WriteLine(variableName + " = " + variableValue);
}
```

}

Created a `FloatReader` class that allows you to register local variables by name and access their values using the `GetVariable` method. Use delegates (`Func<float>`) to capture the value of the local variables, you avoid the complexities of trying to access local variables directly through reflection.